# Random doubles are always infinite

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have the following:

```
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 randEng(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rg(std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(), std::numeric_limits<double>::max());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < numToGenerate; i++){
        nums[i] = rg(randEng);
        std::cout << nums[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

Where `nums` is  a vector presized to `numToGenerate`

Every number that is printed out though says `inf` my understanding was that I had set this up to get random numbers between in this case `-1.79769e+308` and `1.79769e+308` as it happens to be on my machine. What am I doing wrong here in the set up of this random number generator

Comment: what's `nums`? How do you initialize it? If it's a vector, you probably need to `resize()` it beforehand or use `push_back` to avoid undefined behavior by writing out-of-bounds.

Comment: There's no definition for nums. How is it defined?

Comment: `nums` is a vector that is presized to be of size `numToGenerate`

Comment: The constraint is mentioned [in the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution/uniform_real_distribution): *Requires that a <= b and b-a <= std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the computation of the pseudorandom number includes the difference (max-min). For example to compute a random number between `A` and `B` a simple approach would be:

```
x = A + rnd*(B - A)
```

where `rnd` is a random number between 0 and 1. If you do this with the maximum and minimum double precision value you get a problem, because that difference is bigger than the maximum and thus will become "infinite".

After that `A + rnd*infinite` is always infinite if `rnd` is not zero, and NaN when it's zero.